# Is it possible to use CANopen for USB communication?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I have an idea.
USB singals are differential singals and they look the same as CAN-bus signals, even if they are USB signals.

Is it possible to use CANopen protocol to transfer USB signals to other devices?
For example, if I connecting the USB differential cabels like this simple "hub".
I borrow this picture. I know that this is not how a USB hub working, but it's just for illustrate the idea that CANopen can be used with USB signals? Or does it?

[image]

What is the most commonly protocol for transmitting messages in USB?

Comment: USB is USB, CAN is CAN. You can place a "gateway" between, that will translate one to another.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for your reply! I understand that USB is USB. Do you recommend som protocol for USB if I want to have communication between a PC and a microcontroller?

Answer (score 4):

> they look the same as CAN-bus signals,

no. That's wrong; end of story, really.

> Is it possible to use CANopen protocol to transfer USB signals to other devices?

no.

> For example, if I connecting the USB differential cabels like this simple "hub".

That doesn't work with USB; a hub in USB **must** be an active device. You **cannot** connect two USB devices in parallel to the same data lines. You say you know this, and it's true, this doesn't work.

> I want to have communication between a PC and a microcontroller?

Completely different topic!

So, do what everyone does: Either get a microcontroller that does USB natively (high likelihood that your CAN-enabled microcontroller does), or get a USB-to-serial converter and use that with your microcontroller's UART.

Of course, you can also use a USB-to-CAN adapter and talk to your microcontroller's CAN interface, same idea really. But then your microcontroller "talks" CAN, not USB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What type of protocol should I use with USB? It must be some kind of way to have a proper communication?